# How to set a linkbutton's state based on a condition?

Tags: c#, css, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap

I've got 2 linkbuttons, they are linked to a multiview and depending on which I push will change the active view. I want the linkbutton of it's respective view to appear as it is active state.

```html
<asp:Panel runat="server" >
        <div>
            <asp:LinkButton ID="linkDeviceList"  CommandName="SwitchViewByID" CommandArgument="viewDeviceList" runat="server" OnClick="linkDeviceList_Click" CssClass="button-link">Device List</asp:LinkButton>
            <asp:LinkButton ID="linkFTPFolders"  CommandName="SwitchViewByID" CommandArgument="viewFTPFolders" runat="server" OnClick="linkFTPFolders_Click" CssClass="button-link">FTP Folders</asp:LinkButton>           
        </div>
    </asp:Panel>
```

The event handlers. I assumed I'd change the button's state in a 'while' but can't figure out how to apply the style change.

```html
protected void linkFTPFolders_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MultiView1.SetActiveView(viewFTPFolders);

        while (MultiView1.GetActiveView() == viewFTPFolders)
        {
            
        }
    }

    protected void linkDeviceList_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MultiView1.SetActiveView(viewDeviceList);
        while (MultiView1.GetActiveView() == viewDeviceList)
        {
            
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar control. And this is what I did.

1. I removed/added the "active" class on the button that was clicked.
2. I disabled the button that was clicked so that it can't be clicked
   again.

   ```
       protected void lbListView_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
       {
           lbGridView.CssClass = "btn btn-default btn-sm pull-right dt-margin-left-5";
           lbGridView.Enabled = true;

           lbListView.CssClass = "btn btn-default btn-sm pull-right dt-margin-left-5 active";
           lbListView.Enabled = false;

           repGridResults.Visible = false;
           repListResults.Visible = true;
       }

       protected void lbGridView_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
       {
           lbListView.CssClass = "btn btn-default btn-sm pull-right dt-margin-left-5";
           lbListView.Enabled = true;

           lbGridView.CssClass = "btn btn-default btn-sm pull-right dt-margin-left-5 active";
           lbGridView.Enabled = false;

           repListResults.Visible = false;
           repGridResults.Visible = true;
       }
   ```

Comment: I'm new to using boostrap and I'm forming a love/hate relationship real quick. Your answer helped me get closer to my desired outcome thanks.

Comment: What is it that you actually wanted? Did you manage to resolve the issue? If so, please post your code as an answer (answer your own question).

Comment: Sorry I have not resolved this issue yet, I'll have to come back to this another time.